# What is Function in javascript for?

Tags: javascript

When does javascript makes use of Function?? I thought:

```
function anyfunc(){}
```

would the same if:

```
console.log(anyfunc === Function)
```

but that returns false, why? isn't anyfunc a Function?

Answer (score 3):

And also `"Socrates" === "man"` is false. For the same reason.

What you are looking for is

```js
anyfunc instanceof Function
```

`Function` is a class. And in javascript, classes are variables like other.

Which means that you could wonder what is the type of "Function" itself. In some language it would have been "Class". But in js classes are implemented as functions. Which makes it hairy. Because then Function is a Function! `Function instanceof Function` is true!
Which is normally not the case for any `x instanceof x`.

In many languages "Class" would be an instance of "Class" (the object representing the class is itself an object, so derive from Class). But since in javascript classes are in reality functions... that makes the answer to your question tricky.

But well, retain that `somefunc !== Function`. Those are two different variables, with two differents values. But `somefunc instanceof Function`

Comment: in order to anyfunc be an instance of Function shouldn' Function be the anyfunc prototype?

Comment: Yes, indeed. And so it is.

Comment: I get your point but why javascript does not make it explicit like in Array case? the prototype of an Array is shown in console to be Array

Comment: Well, in my browser it is shown. Not the same way as arrays (you have to "unroll"). But that is a display question more than anything. Plus, function are Function instances. But they are not just that. It is a quite important and central type of the language. For example the fact that class themselves are in fact functions. So they deserve a special treatment.  Note that there is no (afaik) rules saying what the console is supposed to display. For example, in my browser, ``/bla/`` is shown without the class "RegExp" mentioned in the first line neither (only if you unroll, like for functions)

Comment: in my browser the prototype of a function is Object.__proto___ weird isn't it?

Comment: As for your initial question (when does JS uses ``Function``), well rarely in most js developers life (I don't think I've ever used it in real code. Then, I am not a real JS developer). But it could be used precisely to wonder if the content of a variable is a function. Imagine for example that you have a curve plotting function, whose parameter can be either an array of data to plot, or a function to plot (y=f(x) graph). Your plotting function may check if its argument is a function by checking if ``arg instanceof Function``

Comment: Although I usually prefer the more traditional ``typeof arg === "function"``.

Comment: googd points but I'm intrigued that here it goes like: console.log(anyfunc.prototype  === Object.__proto__)//true and not console.log(anyfunc === Function) and we both know Object.__proto__ is not Function

Comment: Yes it is! As I said, in Javascript classes ARE function (all this inherit from the way scheme was implementing objects. Strangely, ECMA's team inherit a lot from scheme world. Strangely, because at first glance nobody would believe that scheme and javascript has anything in common). But, well, whatever the reason, classes, like Object and Function are functions. ``Object instanceof Function`` is true. ``Function instance Function`` is true. ``AnyClass instanceof Function`` is true. And, of course ``anyfunc instanceof Function`` is true.

Comment: Therefore it is normal that ``anyfunc.__proto__ === Object.__proto__``. That just mean that ``anyfunc`` and ``Object`` (the thing in the variable named ``Object``, that is the class Object) are both functions, so both are prototype of the same thing. But ``anyfunc !== Object`` nor ``anyfunc !== Function``

Comment: clear enough thank you!

Comment: @guerdoosinfu You can use `console.dir(myFunc)` (or just `dir(myFunc)` in the console) to show the function as an object.
Which allow you to see also its prototype chain.
This also works for any other object like `HTMLElements` that by default are shown as html code instead of an object.

Answer (score 0):

A function is used to take input and output something else. Example:

```
function myFunc() {
  console.log("Hello this is myFunc");
}
```

This will log "Hello this is myFunc" in the console. You can take in parameters and use them as variables. Example:

```
function myFunc(x, y) {
   console.log(x * y);
}
myFunc(5, 5);
```

This will output 25.

What you were trying to do:

> console.log(anyfunc === Function)
> Can be achieved like so:

```
const myfunc = function() {
   console.log("hello");
}
if(typeof myfunc === "function") {
   alert("Yes, myfunc is a function");
}
```

Comment: function and Function are the same?

Comment: I believe they are the same.

Comment: No they are not. ``function`` is a keyword of the language. ``Function`` is just a variable (you can even overwrite it, although you really shouldn't), namely a variable containing the class whose functions are prototype.